# Strings B word assignment

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have to write a program where a user to enter 5 words, these words must be stored into a string array.  When the user is finished, you must display the number of times a word beginning with the letter ‘B’ was entered, lower or uppercase, and also re-state the B words. I can't get it to tell me how many 'B' words there is and what they are.I use java, ready to program since I'm a student, I don't use scanner and all that

```
    //Asking user to input 5 words
    System.out.println ("Please enter 5 words");
    System.out.println ("====================");

    //set up loop so that x is the index variable going from 0 to 4
    //fill words array with five words
    int fromIndex = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int x = 0 ; x <= 4 ; x = x + 1)
    {
        System.out.print (" ");
        words [x] = keyboardInput.readLine ();

      //change word to lowercase
      String lower = words[x].toLowerCase();
      while(fromIndex !=-1)
        {
        fromIndex = lower.indexOf("b",fromIndex);
        if (fromIndex !=-1) 
          {
          //character was matched
          counter = counter + 1;
          fromIndex++;
          }
        }
    }
    System.out.print ("You entered " + counter + " 'B' words and they were: ");
```

This is what I get:

## Please enter 5 words

Food

Billy

Sill

Bear

Pop

You entered 0 'B' words and they were:

Comment: You've got several nice answers building, so I won't add yet another way of doing it, but you should consider `trim()`-ing the entered string, in case there are extra spaces at the front of it

Answer (score 1):

You never reset your `fromIndex`, and you don't need a `fromIndex` or a `while` loop like that. I would use [`String.startsWith(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-). Like,

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
    words[x] = keyboardInput.readLine();
    if (words[x].toLowerCase().startsWith("b")) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Alternatively,

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(words[x].charAt(0)) == 'b') {
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `indexOf` function on your `String`. If that is `0` it means your word Starts with `b`.

```
for (int x = 0 ; x <= 4 ; x = x + 1)
{
  System.out.print (" ");
  words [x] = keyboardInput.readLine ();

  //change word to lowercase
  String lower = words[x].toLowerCase();
  if(lower.indexOf("b") == 0){
     counter++;
  }
}
System.out.print ("You entered " + counter + " 'B' words and they were: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete version:

```
public class Bwords {
public static void main(String [] args){
    java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Please enter 5 words");
    System.out.println ("====================");
    String[] words = new String[5];
    int count=0;
    String  [] b_words=new String[5];


        for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++) {
            System.out.print(x+1+" word: ");
            words[x] = input.next();
             if (words[x].toLowerCase().startsWith("b")) {
                 count++;
                 b_words[x]=words[x];
             }

    }
    System.out.print ("You entered " + count + " 'B' words and they were: ");

    for (String b_word : b_words) {
        if (b_word != null)
            System.out.print(b_word + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

Please enter 5 words

1 word: Food

2 word: Billy

3 word: Sill

4 word: Bear

5 word: Pop

You entered 2 'B' words and they were: Billy Bear